# Login to multiple ttys from one tty

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, login-script, tty

Let's say I am logged into the terminal tty1 and now I would like to run a script from tty1 that would log me in automatically to tty2, tty3, tty4. Of course, I do not want to type the password and the username everywhere since I am already on tty1 authenticated.

Question:
What should I write in the script if my login name is 'user' and password '123456'?

Comment: I did some search on the Internet, but it seems to me it would be better if the answer was in one place.

Comment: if this means you have the answer, you can post the answer below, then accept your answer after 24? hr delay, thus gaining valuable reputation points. Good luck.

Comment: No, I do not have the answer, but I think I would be able to find it after a few hours, but this seems to be a common problem, so someone who has encountered it will write the answer in a few minutes that will serve to many. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Normally is not a good practice to have the password of a user in a script file.
I would suggest to use the public key ssh authentication.

Here an example in [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) to setup the public key auth. Not sure which distro you use, but it is pretty similar in all of them.

this is an example in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  ssh -n -ttt user@localhost &
done
```

The script works only if you have followed the above tutorial to enable the ssh login with the public key.

Depending on what you need to achieve, you can also use screen. [Here](http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/screen.html) a good tutorial on how to use it.

With [chvt](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-7.html) you can switch between tty.

Another cool software, to execute the same command from one ssh session on multiple server is: [ssh cluster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)

Comment: If I want to keep ssh closed then I would have to use '/dev/MAKEDEV tty$i' as mentioned in the link you provided. I just wander how to make it run /bin/login with the authentication automatically.

Comment: I have used 'screen' before. But if you think that that effect is possible to achieve with it, let me know and I'll inspect it more. Because in fact what I want to do is that, first the script would log me into 4 ttys and then screen would open different terminals in each of them. So that I could use ALT+Fn and CTRL+A+N to control hierarchies of open terminals. You can imagine how tedious it is to perform the same commands over again.

Comment: I know that XMonad would be great for such things, but I would like to try it without it.